# mvn mybatis java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource

Tags: spring, maven, mybatis

I am trying to build my first mvn project using MyBatis and Spring.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

following is the project structure:

```
my-project
|
|_ conf --> spring-conf.xml
|
|_ main 
    |
    |_ java
    |
    |_ resources
           |
           |_ persistence --> mybatis.xml
```

When I run a junit to thes the connection with the DB it gives the follow:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseManager' defined in file [O:\WORKSPACE\my-project\conf\spring-conf.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'databaseManagerTarget' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'databaseManagerTarget' defined in file [O:\WORKSPACE\my-project\conf\spring-conf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contentRepositoryDao' 
while setting bean property 'contentRepositoryDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentRepositoryDao' 
defined in file [O:\WORKSPACE\my-project\conf\spring-conf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in file [O:\WORKSPACE\my-project\conf\spring-conf.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/persistence/mybatis.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at it.ereadis.contentrepository.DatabaseManagerUnitTest.<init>(DatabaseManagerUnitTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

the references to the mybatis.xml is defined as follow in the spring-conf.xml

```
    <!-- SESSION FACTORY -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:resources/persistence/mybatis.xml" />  
</bean>
```

Any ideas, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you miss mybatis.xml from your classpath during test run. Try adding to pom (I am not sure exact path):

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>resources/persistence/mybatis.xml</directory>
        </testResource>
   </testResources>
</build>
```